# Redmine via Docker - cannot access Git repositories

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, redmine

I have some strange issue:

Just migrated Redmine from classic installation to Docker (3.4-passenger) - https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine/

Everything works well, but I cannot use Git repositories.
Directories are mapped well (using shared with GitLab), chmod seems ok (tried chmod -R a+rwx).
I can access repos from Docker container's shell, but...

When I add project's new repo, add a path (ie /srv/git/repo-name.git) and go to the https://red.example.com/projects/test-project/repository
i still see this error message:

404 - The entry or revision was not found in the repository.

Please, any clue? Or hot to debug?

Comment: Typo: *how to debug?

Comment: Please show us your Dockerfile and/or docker-compose files